# ActivationConfigProperty userName will be ignored since it is not allowed by resource adapter: hornetq-ra

Tags: java, jboss7.x, ejb-jar.xml

This is my `ejb-jar.xml`:

```
<ejb-jar version="3.0">
    <enterprise-beans>
        <message-driven>
            <ejb-name>myMDB</ejb-name>
            <activation-config>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>destinationType
                    </activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>javax.jms.Queue
                    </activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>destination
                    </activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>queue/test
                    </activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>connectionParameters
                    </activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>host=localhost;port=5445
                    </activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>username
                    </activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>xxx
                    </activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>password
                    </activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>yyy
                    </activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
            </activation-config>
        </message-driven>
    </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

I don't understand why I get this warning :

```
ActivationConfigProperty username will be ignored since it is not allowed by resource adapter: hornetq-ra
```

I tried also `userName` and `UserName` but I always get the same warning.

Should I configure any ra.xml file?

Thank you for your help guys.

Remark : I use JBoss AS 7.2

Comment: Activation config properties are 1-to-1 with activation spec properties in the resource adapter. It appears that the resource adapter's activation spec does not have a `username`, `userName`, or `UserName` property. Searching, it appears that `UserName` is a resource adapter property, but I'm not familiar enough with JBoss to give a suggestion on how to configure that other than to say it appears an activation config property is not the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

JBoss doesn't recognize the property "username". Change it to "user" and it should pick it up fine.  For reference, here's a list of what JBoss looks for as far as the ActivationConfigProperties goes:

https://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/tutorial/1.0.7/html/Message_Driven_Beans.html